# R: Only loading when using data.tables in new package gives error on keyed subset

Tags: r, data.table, package

I'm writing an R package in which I use some data.table functionalities (specifically keying and subsetting based on keys). I read somewhere that in order to write a 'good' package, I needed to ensure that data.table only needed to be loaded, and not attached. So I made sure when writing the code that I didn't attach data.table, but rather directed the function calls to the data.table namespace using the `data.table::` command. An example would be:

```
ExampleFunction<-function(){
  set.seed(2)
  DT<-data.table::data.table(a=sample(letters[1:5],20,T),b=sample(1:2,20,T),c=1:20)
  data.table::setkeyv(DT,c("a","b"))
  return(DT[list("a",2),])
}
```

Note that the return line uses a command which only works on data.tables, but that I cannot specify the data.table namespace in the standard way (as that would search for DT in the data.table namespace). Regardless, running this function from the console (without having data.table attached) gives the expected output:

```
> ExampleFunction()
   a b  c
1: a 2  1
2: a 2 14
```

However, when I build my package (with data.table listed in the description as an import, not a dependency), and run the same function I get the following error:

```
> ExampleFunction()
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

With the following traceback:

```
4. `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) 
3. `[.data.table`(DT, list("a", 2), ) at Examples.R#5
2. DT[list("a", 2), ] at Examples.R#5
1. ExampleFunction()
```

The traceback shows that this error occurs in the return line of the function, meaning that it no longer recognises this as a data.table command. My question is why does this go wrong within the package, if it works outside of the package? Does my package need to depend on data.table instead of just importing it? And lastly is there a way I can specify that `DT[list("a",2),]` is a data.table command?

Comment: Fyi, there is a related vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by including import(data.table) into the namespace of my own package. Feel pretty stupid now.